is it possible to disable tcp timestamps on aws api gateway (or it's cloudfront distribution)
the latest pci compliance rules require disabling tcp timestamps as described in rfc1323 and rfc7323. is it possible to configure either aws api-gateway or the associated cloudfront proxy to disable this feature?
details:
the typical way to disable this feature on a linux server is to run this command: sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0
the latest pci compliance specification can be found here: https://docs-prv.pcisecuritystandards.org/PCI%20DSS/Standard/PCI-DSS-v4_0_1.pdf
side note: it appears that aws randomizes the tcp timestamps on a per-connection basis to prevent an attacker from detecting server restarts, but i can't find any documentation to support this theory. is there any such documentation?

It feels like this is a non-issue with a service like API Gateway or Cloudfront because there isn't really a server sitting behind whatever these are in front of.  On your Linux server, that makes sense but there isn't a reboot of, for example, API Gateway to exploit.  Random timestamps seems to be the way most O/S's are handling this now.  However, I feel that this isn't really a programming question - https://serverfault.com/ is likely a better place.

i agree entirely that this pci compliance rule doesn't really make sense, but i'm really just looking for documentation for my auditor. it's much easier to simply remove this security feature or point them to an aws document saying it's not possible, than to write a 200 page whitepaper explaining why it's a counter-productive requirement

considering most people configure their aws services using cloudformation, this feels like a "programming" question. although i think this might also fit on serverfault.com

Both comments make sense - totally agree that it's easier to quote than write and these are the kinds of questions that seem to cross concerns.
